# Use SwiftUI View file inside Objective C framework

Tags: swift, objective-c, swiftui, frameworks

I am building an objective C framework in which I want to show a screen when a function is called from the app that will import the framework. I am trying to use the swift code as I have seen in some articles.

ProfileView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
@available(iOS 13.0.0, *)
struct ProfileView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
    
}

struct ProfileView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProfileView()
    }
}
```

ProfileViewInterface.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.0.0, *)
@objc class ProfileViewInterface : NSObject {

    @objc static func profileViewController() -> UIViewController {
        return UIHostingController(rootView: ProfileView())
    }

}
```

Objective C code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyApi.h"
#import <xxxFramework/xxxFramework-Swift.h>

@implementation MyApi

- (void) openProfile:(UIViewController*)controller :(UIWindow*) window {
    
    UIViewController *profileViewController = [[ProfileViewInterface new] profileViewController];
    controller = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:profileViewController];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
@end
```

I keep getting the error:
Use of undeclared identifier 'ProfileViewInterface'

I have already set the SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME to xxxframework-Swift.h
I also have to mention that bridging headers are not allowed in frameworks.

Any thoughts?

Comment: They should be `public` and `profileViewController` static method, you don't need instantiate `ProfileViewInterface`

Comment: I added the keyword public to the interface and the function and the new error is : No visible @interface for 'ProfileViewInterface' declares the selector 'profileViewController'

Comment: Have you removed `new]`?